# How to format drive after installing berryboot

Tags: sd-card

When I first got my Raspberry PI, I decided that I would install Berryboot. Overall, It's really cool. But now my files are corrupt. I've lost 3 SD cards like this. When I go into windows, It doesn't show the ext4 partition, only the FAT boot partition. How would I go about formatting my drive as a whole?

Comment: Windows doesn't natively support any ext type. There's software which can decode it.

Comment: *"But now my files are corrupt."* -> Why do you believe that?  I'm asking because I think most reports of SD card corruption on the pi are mistaken...

Comment: It black screens, crashes, says files may be corrupt and Why does it matter? My question is just how do I format it? Not to sound rood or anything.

Comment: also, @thekiwi5000, I tried, but it doesn't let me format it.

Comment: *"Why does it matter?"* -> I'm just curious about this, because it seems some people **never** have any problems with corruption, even after years, and some people  complain they are plagued by them.  So I'm trying to decide if they are correct, and if so, why it happens to them but nobody else.  It *could* be a certain percentage of pi's are just defective, but I think there are a few other possibilities as well.

Comment: I think mine is defective, I'm really formatting it bc/ I need to sell it by 2morrow. The analog outputs word fine tho.

Comment: @goldilocks In my case, I knew the sd was corrupted due to a kernel panic at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this website: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Download the software, run, select the SD card drive and it will completely format everything on the SD card no matter what file system was used.

Comment: Thank You SO much @Matthew, Never could've figured it out myself!

Comment: This did not work for me. It told me that everything had formatted and installed correctly, but when I booted up my pi it was still stuck on BerryBoot. I wouldn't mind as much if it would actually install any of the images I'm trying to install, rather than just telling me it did and rebooting to the same single image.

Comment: If the above software doesn't work its probably a problem with the sd card. After the format, does it say the full size of the sd card?

Answer (score -2):

1. Many laptops seem to have a buggy SD card slot, badly supported by Windows. Ever been told by Windows that the SD card must be formatted? There's a 99% chace that using a Linux OS might fix it.
2. It might sound obvious, but could the little slider on your microSD-to-SD adapter be set to read-only? Also, try using a better quality adapter in case that works.